# Как вырезать объект из одного массива и переложить в другой

Tags: javascript

Ниже расположена функция которая проходится по массиву, вырезает нужные объекты и перекладывает их в другой.

```
getSavedArray : function() {
    let serviceArr = [...galleryModule.hiddenArray];
    let arr = this.service.getLocalStorage("saved-gallery");
    arr = arr.split(",");
    galleryModule.hiddenArray.forEach((item,param) => {
        arr.forEach(elem => {
            if(elem == item.id) {
                galleryModule.visibleArray = galleryModule.visibleArray.concat(serviceArr.splice(param, 1));
            }
        })
    })
    galleryModule.hiddenArray = serviceArr;
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при удалении сокращается число элементов в массиве и обращение к массиву по индексу становится не корректным. Вопрос как можно решить подобную проблему?

Comment: Решить просто - никогда не редактировать массив, по которому проходится цикл. Создать копию массива, например. Или записывать индексы для удаления и удалить уже после цикла

Comment: Я так и сделал, создал дубль массива. Итерируюсь по основному, удаляю из дубликата. В Дубликате и происходит удаление индексов и в последующем не корректная работа.

Comment: Удаляйте в обратном порядке, чтоб индексы не съезжали, например

Comment: Вопрос решился с помощью простого for. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы обеспечить корректный обход с удалением, наиболее простой способ - использование посконного цикла for, но с обходом с конца

```
 for (idx = serviceArr.length - 1; idx>=0; idx--)
    {проверили  serviceArr[idx], удалили, если нужно}
```

Comment: Вопрос решился с помощью простого for. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можете прочитать вот эти 2 статьи и станет понятнее:

1. [Работа с массивами](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods)
2. [Метод slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

С `slice` сможете оптимизировать код.
А чтобы решить проблему, просто получаете объект из массива без его обрезки.
Можете через forEach пройтись по [Array.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys).

Ещё можете посмотреть на [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (можете использовать его в текущем коде).

Comment: суть именно в том, что необходимо вырезать, это и является корнем зла. В конечном итоге должно быть 2 массива с разными объектами.

Comment: @IgorGarnik если проблема в том что возникает ошибка при обращение на несуществующий ключ массива, то проверьте через typeof если значение данного ключа не undefined

Comment: Вопрос решился с помощью простого for. Спасибо!

Comment: @IgorGarnik отлично! :)